# How to prove $|f(x)|\leq \frac{3}{2}$ for all $x\in [-1, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a, b, c$ are real numbers. Suppose $f(-1),f(0), f(1) \in[-1, 1]$. Prove that $|f(x)|\leq \frac{3}{2}$ for all $x\in [-1, 1]$.

Here I need to show $|f(x)|\leq \frac{3}{2}$. It means $f(x)$ lies between $-3/2$ and $3/2$. But how can I show that. If I equate $f'(x)$ to $0$ I get $x=-b/2a$.Then stuck. Please help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/774069/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that $|f(1)| \leq 1$ gives $-1 \leq a + b + c \leq 1$, and the condition that
$|f(-1)| \leq 1$ gives $-1 \leq a - b + c \leq 1$. Subtracting these two equations
gives $|b| \leq 1$. The condition that $|f(0)| \leq 1$ gives $|c| \leq 1$.

If $f(x)$ were monotone on $[-1,1]$, then $|f(x)|$ would be maximized at $-1$ or $1$ where $|f(x)| \leq 1$ and we would have nothing to prove. So we can assume $f(x)$ is not monotone on $[-1,1]$, which implies there is an $x_0 \in (0,1)$ where $f'(x_0) = 0$. In other words, $2ax_0 + b = 0$ or $x_0 = -{b \over 2a}$, where $f(x_0) = c - {b^2 \over 4a}$. (If $a = 0$ then the function is monotone, which is covered above.) Note that since $|x_0| < 1$ we have $|{b \over 2a}| < 1$.

$|f(x)|$ is maximized either at an endpoint of the interval or at point where $f'(x) = 0$, which must be $x_0$. Since $|f(x)| \leq 1$ at the endpoints, it remains to show that $|f(x_0)| = |c - {b^2 \over 4a}| \leq {3 \over 2}$. But $|c - {b^2 \over 4a}| \leq |c| + |{b^2 \over 4a}| \leq |c| + {1 \over 2}|b||{b \over 2a}|$, and by the above this is less than $1 + {1 \over 2}*1*1 = {3 \over 2}$.

Comment: nice copy and paste :D

Comment: I went off and solved it, and wrote it in when I came back. I did see you had answered it before I typed it in, but I decided your answer was badly enough written that it would be of value to write my version anyhow.

Comment: well... again, nice copy and paste :D

Comment: If your answer were comprehensible, it would be getting upvotes. Anyhow, I don't care what you think.

Comment: yes, I did not get an upvote for my wrong explanation, that's right... nevertheless, for my wrong explanation, I get a nice copy and paste :D

Comment: The problem is your English, not your math. For example, I have no idea what you just wrote above. Your answer was mathematically correct, but written in bad English. This is why I chose to write in my answer despite you having given a solution which was similar to the one I came up with. Rather than making false accusations, perhaps you'd be better off working on your English writing skills. There's no point answering questions if people cannot understand you. (I understood your answer because I had just solved the problem).

Comment: A comment to my answer to criticize my English (I'm not English) would have been a nicer thing than a very similar answer. I stop it here. I won't talk about this anymore. Bye :D

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = [-1, 1]$. We know that:

$f(0) = c \in I$, $f(1) = a + b + c \in I$ and $f(-1) = a - b + c \in I$.
If we subtract the third from the second, we have that:

$f(1) - f(-1) = 2b \Rightarrow b = \frac{f(1)-f(-1)}{2} \in I$

Now, assume that $a>0$. Let $x_m$ and $x_M$ be the points where we have, respectively, the minimum and maximum of the parabola in $I$.

The maximum point candidates are $-1$ and $1$ (borders of $I$). In both cases we will have that $f(x_M) \leq 1 < \frac{3}{2}$.

The candidates to be the minimum are $-1, 1$ (borders of $I$) and $-\frac{b}{2a}$ if this is in $I$. If the minimum is attained at $-1$ or at $1$, then we are ok since in both cases we will have that $-\frac{3}{2} < -1 \leq f(x_m)$.

If $x_m = -\frac{b}{2a} \in I$, then the minimum is $f(x_m) = c - \frac{b^2}{4a} = c + x_m \frac{b}{2}$.

We know that $b, x_m, c \in I$ and these fact yeld to $f(x_m) = c + x_m \frac{b}{2}\geq -1 +  x_m \frac{b}{2} \geq -1 + (-1)\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{3}{2}$.

This means that, in all the possible cases ($x_m = -1$ or $x_m= 1$ or $x_m = -\frac{b}{2a} \in I$), we have $f(x_m) \geq -\frac{3}{2}$.

So we have that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{3}{2} ~ \forall x \in I \wedge a > 0$

Similar arguments holds assuming that $a < 0$.

Finally, if $a = 0$, then we have a line and minimum and maximum in $I$ are attained on the border points $-1$ and $+1$, so again we are bounded.