# Maximum value of f(x) in the given domain according to the given constraints:

Tags: calculus, quadratics

Let $f(x) =ax^2 +bx+c,$ where $a, b ,c\in\mathbb{R}.$ If $f(-1), f(0) , f(1)\in [-1,1]. $ Then prove that $|f(x) |\le\frac{3}{2}\forall x\in [-1,1]$.

> My method was involving graph :    first of all we can observe that curve of any quadratic is symmetric about some x = k line and that if quadratic has value at f(-1) to be more negative then it will make the maximum reach more value because of greater slope intially . (a>0 case i am considering) from these ideas i first made three blocks of regions  2 of those regions the constraint points are marked so that it will lie inside that region only . Now the third region which goes from $x=1  to  x=2$ (i made that because it was rather easy to observe the symmetric nature of the curve about some $x=k$ axis in this way ) By observation from graph i concluded maximum will be when the $f(1)= 1,f(-1)= -1 and f(0)=1$ which gives the $f(x) = -x^2 +x +1$ curve , whose maximum in that range is $5/4 <3/2$ , so did i finished correctly or something is missing in this graph proof?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $|f(x)|\leq \frac{3}{2}$ for all $x\in [-1, 1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288152/how-to-prove-fx-leq-frac32-for-all-x-in-1-1). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clvert%20f(x)%20%5Crvert%20%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1). Also, another duplicate is [Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers. Suppose $f(-1),f(0),f(1) \in [-1,1]$. Prove that $|f(x)|\le \frac{3}{2}$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.](/q/774069).

Comment: The second link in particular shows that $\frac54$ is also an upper bound.

Comment: Thats nice , i would like to know why everywhere = condition was also given ? As such one can see its <=5/4

Comment: I don't see $=$ anywhere in the $3/2$ questions, can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean the question itself , why the problem proposer set the equality one too even though it cannot be achieved @MishaLavrov

Comment: If $|f(x)| \le \frac54$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, then it's also true that $|f(x)| \le \frac32$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. Since it looks like there's an argument that gives $|f(x)| \le \frac32$ without showing $|f(x)| \le \frac54$, probably the problem was posed that way to be easier.

Comment: I see now i understood Misha Lavrov , thanks :)